# Limits and Jacobian for Gaussian Integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, gaussian-integral

Ahoy everyone!
I am new to Gaussian Integrals and my teachers cannot help me out (because they don't get it). So I turn to the Internet for answers. I have very basic doubts and would really appreciate a clear explanation.
1) How do we explain $dxdy = r\cdot dr d\theta$? I am looking for either a simple and intuitive geometric interpretation and/or an algebraic proof which starts from the very basics.
2)While converting cartesian coordinates to polar, I believe the limits for '$r$' are the same as those of $x$ (and $y$) but how do we exactly decide the limits of theta?
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limits of theta ($\theta$) are $0$ and $\infty$, i.e. one full circle. And you should look at the following: https://www.math24.net/double-integrals-polar-coordinates/

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The website you shared clears up the doubts I had about the limits but the first question still feels foggy. I am not quite clear about why we put dxdy = Jacobian drdtheta because I don't understand what the Jacobian is exactly. Could you dumb it down for me?

Comment: @Hardik Rajpal Do you know why the jacobian is used in a double integral? Because if you do, the answer from the site seems straightforward. So should your question be rephrased?

Comment: @hardik rajpal PS the jabobian is used because you convert one area to another area. To even out the difference in size you use the determinant of the jacobian. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant for more information about the determinant, and areas.

Comment: I appreciate the linear algebra involved but it would take me a few months to get the deep understanding I value so much with that road. Is it fine if I just consider dxdy to be an elementary dA (A=area) in cartesian coordinates and rdrdtheta to be the equivalent dA in polar coordinates? It makes a lot more sense with a picture but I am new to the website.

Comment: Indeed, you could say that. The extra $r$ is ‘just’ a scalar that accurs because you convert one area to another. Take the following example: let’s describe the whole plane with $x^2+y^2$ but in polar form you need the extra $r$, otherwise it would be the unit circle (not the whole plane).